# Wordpress to apps via phoneGAP

Tags: wordpress, cordova

I am looking for a tutorial that shows how to use PhoneGAP to convert a Classified Ads website( eg gumtree) that created using wordpress to apps ( ios,andriod and windows). I have spent 3 hours to find something but could not find it :(

I am in the learning stage, appreciate your support.

Comment: [Here][1]


  [1]: http://google.com

Comment: please post some code, this aint a forum for is to google for you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Phonegap to build apps that will read JSON feeds from your Wordpress sites. Here is an idea where to start:

To get the data from your WordPress sites you will need to use a JSON API (you can search google for such APIs) for example: [JetPack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) which includes WordPress JSON API.

You can find quite good [documentation](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) for the API.
Also you can use [OAUTH2](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/) to authenticate.